# rails4.2でEncoding::UndefinedConversionError - "\xE6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8:というエラーになります。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

### 環境

ruby2.2.7
rails4.2.9

### 事象

以下のようにform_forでパラメータを飛ばすとパラメータの中身がascii-8bitになりEncoding::CompatibilityErrorが出てしまいます。

```
= form_for @hoge, :url => {:action => :update} do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag('authenticity_token', form_authenticity_token)
  = f.submit "保存する"
```

パラメータの中身は以下です。utf8の箇所をみてください。

```
Processing by HogeController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"\xE2\x9C\x93", "authenticity_token"=>"jWj10656mdI5VHn+sa}
```

rails4.1.16だと意図通りになっています。

```
Processing by HogeController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jWj10656mdI5VHn+sa}
```

なにが原因そうなのかすら検討もつきません。よろしくお願いします。 
「何か追加で情報があれば検討つくかもしれない」ということなら追加で出しますのでご教授願います。

ちなみにGemfileは以下です

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.9'
gem 'rake' , '10.0.4'

gem 'mysql2', '0.3.14'

gem 'switch_point', '0.8.0'
gem 'google-api-client', '0.8.0'
gem 'tzinfo', '~> 1.1'
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.2"
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'selectable_attr_rails', '0.3.14'
gem 'selectable_attr', '0.3.17'
gem 'acts_as_tree''
gem 'rmagick', '2.16.0'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'crummy', '1.2'
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.2'
gem 'sanitize', '2.0.6'
gem 'jpmobile', '3.0.2' # :git => "git://github.com/jpmobile/jpmobile.git" , :tag => "v1.0.0.pre"
gem 'garb', '0.9.1'
gem 'settingslogic', '2.0.8'
gem 'unicorn', '4.8.3'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '4.0.0'

gem 'delayed_job', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'daemons', '1.1.8'
gem 'rack_after_reply'

gem "romankana", "~> 0.1.3"
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'active_decorator'
gem "RubyInline"

source 'http://gems.github.com/'
gem 'googlecharts', '1.6.8'

gem "redis", "2.2.1"
gem "redis-rails"
gem "redis-objects"
gem 'activerecord-session_store'

gem 'rack-pjax'
gem 'fluent-logger'
gem 'fingerprintjs-rails'

gem 'natto'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'public_suffix'

gem "msgpack"

gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'business_time'

gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'

gem 'rails-observers'

gem 'actionpack-page_caching'

gem 'activeresource', require: 'active_resource'

gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'compass-rails', '3.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'execjs'
```

### 追記1

config/appication.rbに以下を追加

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "ForceParamsEncoding"
```

lib/test.rbというファイルを作成

```
class ForceParamsEncoding
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    params = @request.params
    params.each do |k, v|
      if v.class == Array
        array = []
        array << force_encoding_utf_1(v[0])
        params[k] = array
      elsif v.class == Hash
        params[k] = force_encoding_utf_1(v)
      else
        params[k] = v.force_encoding("UTF-8")
      end
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def force_encoding_utf_1(value)
    value.each do |k, v|
      if v.class == Array
        array = []
        array << force_encoding_utf_2(v[0])
        value[k] = array
      elsif v.class == Hash
        value[k] = force_encoding_utf_2(v)
      else
        value[k] = v.force_encoding("UTF-8")
      end
    end
    return value
  end

  def force_encoding_utf_2(value)
    value.each do |k, v|
      if v.class == Array
        array = []
        array << force_encoding_utf_1(v[0])
        value[k] = array
      elsif v.class == Hash
        value[k] = force_encoding_utf_1(v)
      else
        value[k] = v.force_encoding("UTF-8")
      end
    end
    return value
  end
end
```

（メモなので一旦めちゃくちゃ汚いコードになってます。）

で `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/test"` と無理やり直すように一旦、対応しました。

何か別途方法わかる方いたら随時投げてくださると助かります。

### 追記2

gemが悪さしているというコメントいただいたのでそこは追記3として追加したいと思いますが。。
一旦無理やり直したので追加します。追記1よりはマシかなと。

```
lib/rack/utils.rb


     def parse_nested_query(qs, d = nil)
       params = KeySpaceConstrainedParams.new

       (qs || '').split(d ? /[#{d}] */n : DEFAULT_SEP).each do |p|
         k, v = p.split('=', 2).map { |s| unescape(s) }
　　　　　#unescape(s)部分をURI.decode_www_form_component(s, Encoding::UTF_8)とすると直りました。unescapeのメソッドがなんかおかしくなっている可能性が高いかなと。

         normalize_params(params, k, v)
       end
       return params.to_params_hash
     rescue ArgumentError => e
       raise InvalidParameterError, e.message
     end
```

Comment: 質問にはRails4.2.9とありますがGemfileだと4.0.13になってます。質問を編集して修正してください。おそらくなんかのGemが悪さしてるんだと思います。Gemfile.lockの差分見比べてみるとか、1つずつ消してみるとかで調べてみてください。(これで解決したら何が悪かったか自分で回答してください)

Comment: Gemfileを修正しました。 やはりgemなんですね。ちなみにgemfile自体の差分は```gem 'rails', '4.1.16'' → gem rails', '4.2.9'``` と```gem 'sanitize', '2.0.3' → gem 'sanitize', '2.0.6' ```です。sanitizeの部分とGemfile.lockで追加されているgemを見てみます

Comment: 解決した内容は質問に追記するのではなく回答として投稿してください

Answer (score 1):

原因が判明しました。ご指摘いただいたようにgemが悪さをしていました。

```
gem 'jpmobile', '3.0.2'
```

こいつを最新にしたところ直りました。

```
gem 'jpmobile', '~> 4.2'
```